# how to read data from json to View using jquery mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, viewdata

I have the following data in an array.

```
[{"FirstName":"Nancy","LastName":"Davolio","Title":"Sales Representative"},
{"FirstName":"Andrew","LastName":"Fuller","Title":"Vice President, Sales"}]
```

I want to present this data using jquery into a table like this :

```
 <table id="employee">
 <tr>
 <td>Nancy</td>
 <td>Davolio</td>
 <td>Sales Representative</td>
 ...
 </table>
```

Comment: A bit more context and details would be welcomed. What are you trying to achieve? A sample of the view and backend code would be also great.

Comment: So my goal is, get the data from my controller using ViewData and put the retrieved values on View on just a click of a button using jquery and without refreshing the page, here is the backend code for my View:

Comment: View:@{ var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var employees = @serializer.Serialize(ViewData["Employees"]); }   $("#employee").append("<tr><td>" + "@employees.toString" + "</td></tr>");-so basically I want to append the serialized data to my table which you can see from above.

Comment: @Scott.N, what more do you want than the current supplied answer?

Comment: I got this working using - $.ajax
            (
                {
                    url: 'http://localhost:32709/Emplyees/Get/',
                    type: 'GET',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each
                        (
                        data,
                        function (key, employee) {
                            $("#empTable").append("<tr><td>" + employee.FirstName + "</td></tr>");
                        }
                        );
                    }

                }
            );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

similar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var jsonp = '[{"Lang":"jQuery","ID":"1"},{"Lang":"C#","ID":"2"}]';
      var lang = '';
      var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
      $.each(obj, function() {
          lang += this['Lang'] + "<br/>";
      });
      $('span').html(lang);
    });​
```

Comment: I declared my data using razor at my View page and used serialization '@model IEnumerable<MVCvs2012.Models.Employees>

@{
    var serializer = new    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var employees = @serializer.Serialize(ViewData["Employees"]);
    
}'

Comment: This totally works . . . but the data of my jsonp is coming from a ViewData, can you please advise me on this one? please...

Comment: var jsonp = '@ViewData["key"]';

Comment: Theres no data appending on my table                                           var j = '@ViewData["Employees"]';
var json = $.parseJSON(j); $(json).each(function (i, val) {
                $.each(val, function (k, v) {
                    $("#employee").append("<tr><td>" + k + " : " + v + "</td></tr>");
                });

Comment: make sure @ViewData["Employees"] is a string with json format. You can try alert(j) to test before run function.

Comment: This is what my alert is showing "System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult" and this is my code in my controller    JsonResult o = Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            ViewData["Employees"] = o;

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this before:

```
var apiUrl = 'UrlOfData';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(apiUrl)
        .done(function (data) {
            for (var item in data){
                $('#people').append(item.FirstName);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#people').text('Error: ' + err);
        });
});
```

Comment: **bold**I declared my data using razor at my View page                        '@model IEnumerable<MVCvs2012.Models.Employees>

@{
    var serializer = new    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var employees = @serializer.Serialize(ViewData["Employees"]);
    
}'

Comment: Don't use JavaScriptSerializer... it's kinda terrible.  Try JSON.NET http://james.newtonking.com/json

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need jQuery for this. A foreach in razor should be enough. Something like this should work (given that the model passed is IEnumerable) :

```
<table id="employee">
@foreach (var employee in Model)
{
 <tr>
  <td>@employee.LastName</td>
  <td>@employee.FirstName</td>
  <td>@employee.TItle</td>
 </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: So my goal is, get the data from my controller using ViewData and put the retrieved values on View on just a click of a button using jquery and without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

it is understood that for simple ops like this, manually assemble DOM is okay. But I am still a bit surprised that no one mentioned jquery templating.

see details from this link: [Jquery Template](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template), ***With below contents cited there***.

> The plugin parses a template using data attributes to populate the
>   data. Simply pass in a JavaScript object, and the plugin does the
>   rest.
>
> An example template is below:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
     <div data-content="author"></div>
     <div data-content="date"></div>
     <img data-src="authorPicture" data-alt="author"/>
     <div data-content="post"></div> </script>
```

> And to use this do the following:

```
 $("#template-container").loadTemplate($("#template"),
     {
         author: 'Joe Bloggs',
         date: '25th May 2013',
         authorPicture: 'Authors/JoeBloggs.jpg',
         post: 'This is the contents of my post'
     });
```

> Similarly the content of the template could be held in a separate html file without the enclosing script tag, and used like the
>   following:

```
 $("#template-container").loadTemplate("Templates/template.html",
     {
         author: 'Joe Bloggs',
         date: '25th May 2013',
         authorPicture: 'Authors/JoeBloggs.jpg',
         post: 'This is the contents of my post'
     });
```

> The plugin has a number of data-... attributes that can be used to populate various attributes with the data. There is also the
>   powerful data-template-bind attribute that accepts a JSON object,
>   enabling binding to any attribute, or the content of the element.